# jQuery looping through .children of .children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking over previously asked questions and can't seem to find a solution for my scenario...

I'd like to be able to loop through all children and children of children, etc...

the markup from design looks similar to this

```
<div>
  <div>
   <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to select all labels within a specific div, regardless of their direct parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to select all labels within a specific div, regardless of their direct parent.

It's just [CSS selector notation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Assuming that `<div>` has an ID of `myDiv`:

```
$('#myDiv label').each(function ()
{
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: working great man, I'm new to jquery and was getting stumped trying to use children, obviously in the wrong case. This just opened up a world of easy for me :)

Comment: Learn to dig through the jQuery API docs. They will answer 99% of your questions. The documentation is quite good.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to keep stepping down through children in order to find labels within a specific div. This will do the job for you:

```
$('#idOfDiv label')
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('div label')` will select any descendant of that div, regardless of depth. If you want it to be children or children of children, you can select like `$('div > label, div > * > label')`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` function (instead of `children`) like so: `$('#container').find('label')`

Comment: yeah, apparently `$('#container label')` is the same as `$('#container').find('label')`. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('div:first').find('label')` will give you each label element

Answer (score 0):

To select all labels:

```
$('label').something();
```

To select all labels contained in a div:

```
$('label', 'div').something();
```

Comment: Using the context argument like that is just plain silly. $('div label') is equivalent and much more idiomatic.